# R data.table increment by category and set NA to last non-missing value

Tags: r, data.table

**[Background]**

I have some data of online activities from a group of users:

- `userId` indicates the ID of the user.
- `pageType` indicates the current page the user is on. `home` indicates the homepage, while `content` indicates the content page.
- The pages are already sorted by time, so row 1 happens before row 2, and row 2 happens before row 3, ...
- Actual data has roughly 2 million rows, and 8 page types. `userId` is a 36-charactered `java.util.UUID` object.

**[Goal]**

I want to generate a new column for each `pageType` and count the number of previous page views (not including current) of the the exact same type.

**[Sample Data]**

To generate a sample of the actual data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table("userId"=rep(1:3, each=10),
                 "pageType"=c("home", "content", "home", "content", "home", "home", "content", "content", "home", "home",
                              "content", "content", "home", "home", "content", "home", "home", "content", "home", "content",
                              "home", "home", "content", "content", "home", "home", "content", "content", "home", "content"))

> DT
    userId pageType
 1:      1     home
 2:      1  content
 3:      1     home
 4:      1  content
 5:      1     home
 6:      1     home
 7:      1  content
 8:      1  content
 9:      1     home
10:      1     home
...    ...      ...
```

**[My Attempts]**

I have tried to solve this problem in two ways, but both of them are too slow. I also feel my solution didn't use `data.table` the way it is designed for.

**Solution I**

1. Filter by `pageType` and increment by `userId`.
2. Set missing values for the other `pageType`.

Below is the code:

```
FixPageView <- function(data, type) {
  val <- 0
  for (i in 1:nrow(data)) {
    if (is.na(data[[type]][i])) {
      set(data, i, type, val)
    } else {
      val <- data[[type]][i]
    }
  }
}
DT[pageType=="home", numHomePagesViewed:=0:(.N-1), by=userId]
DT[pageType=="content", numContentPagesViewed:=0:(.N-1), by=userId]
FixPageView(DT, "numHomePagesViewed")
FixPageView(DT, "numContentPagesViewed")

> DT
    userId pageType numHomePagesViewed numContentPagesViewed
 1:      1     home                  0                     0
 2:      1  content                  0                     0
 3:      1     home                  1                     0
 4:      1  content                  1                     1
 5:      1     home                  2                     1
 6:      1     home                  3                     1
 7:      1  content                  3                     2
 8:      1  content                  3                     3
 9:      1     home                  4                     3
10:      1     home                  5                     3
...    ...      ...                ...                   ...
```

**Solution II**

Double `for` loop and set it row by row.

```
DT[, numHomePagesViewed := 0L][, numContentPagesViewed := 0L]
for (i in unique(DT$userId)) {
  home_inc <- -1L
  content_inc <- -1L
  for (j in 1L:nrow(DT[userId==i])) {
    if (DT$pageType[(i-1L)*10L + j] == "home") {
      home_inc <- home_inc + 1L
      set(DT, (i-1L)*10L + j, "numHomePagesViewed", home_inc)
    } else {
      set(DT, (i-1L)*10L + j, "numHomePagesViewed", max(0, home_inc))
    }
    if (DT$pageType[(i-1L)*10L + j] == "content") {
      content_inc <- content_inc + 1L
      set(DT, (i-1L)*10L + j, "numContentPagesViewed", content_inc)
    } else {
      set(DT, (i-1L)*10L + j, "numContentPagesViewed", max(0, content_inc))
    }
  }
}

> DT
    userId pageType numHomePagesViewed numContentPagesViewed
 1:      1     home                  0                     0
 2:      1  content                  0                     0
 3:      1     home                  1                     0
 4:      1  content                  1                     1
 5:      1     home                  2                     1
 6:      1     home                  3                     1
 7:      1  content                  3                     2
 8:      1  content                  3                     3
 9:      1     home                  4                     3
10:      1     home                  5                     3
...    ...      ...                ...                   ...
```

**[Question]**

1. What can I do to improve the speed?
2. Is there a more "`data.table`" way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try:

```
DT[,lapply(unique(pageType),
   function(x) pmax(cumsum(pageType==x)-1,0)),by=userId]
```

Next, you have to rename the obtained columns.

As suggested in the comments, you can assign the names with one line:

```
DT[, paste0("num",unique(DT$pageType),"PagesViewed") := 
      lapply(unique(pageType), function(x) pmax(cumsum(pageType==x)-1,0)), by=userId]
```

Comment: Actually, do you mind updating your answer to this? It does the naming all at once: `DT[, c("numHomePagesViewed", "numContentPagesViewed") := lapply(unique(pageType), function(x) pmax(cumsum(pageType==x)-1,0)), by=userId]`